# Minor bug in date of multiple bounties on same question

Tags: support, profile-page, bounties

In time I offered more than one bounty on the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654684/). But on my profile page it looks like I offered these bounties all on the same day:

[image: bounty profile page]

Comment: You can add as many bounties as you like of 500 rep since you can't double that.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you were simply out of options after a 300+ bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date you see there is *not* the day you posted or awarded the bounty. It corresponds to the latest activity on the question, which is an edit on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083851/4751173). In the question in between, it is the day the bounty was posted, because that actually counts as 'activity' on a question.

This behaviour is consistent with other tabs in your profile, e.g. the list of favourite questions.